# jqGrid: AfterSave method not firing, when using action formatter and filters to edit cell values then show grid with new cell value and filtered grid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to use the action formatter to enable inline grid editing.  I've set the grid to loadonce: true and am retrieving JSON data to populate the grid.

I've also added a navbar button to filter cell values that are all zero in the row, so as to only show rows with at least one non-zero value.

When attempting to edit the filtered rows, how can I edit the cell values, send the values to the server, reload the grid, and then apply the filter the grid?

I've attempted to incorporate a trigger to reload the grid in the formatoption function afterSave, but the new value is not displayed, the original value is shown and applying the filter to the grid also fails.

```
$grid.jqGrid({ 
    url: gridLoadURL,
    datatype: "json",
 mtype: "GET",
 caption: gridCaption,
 loadonce: true,
 majCostExcel: majCostExcel,
 //loadCostRowData: CostRowData,
 editurl: CostRowData,
 loadCostData: CostData,
 //footerrow: false,
 altRow: true,
 altClass: "altRow",
 loadtext: "Loading",
 colNames: ['Actions','Allocation ID','Project Name','2012 Qtr 1','2012 Qtr 2','2012 Qtr 3','2012 Qtr 4','2013 Qtr 1','2013 Qtr 2','2013 Qtr 3','2013 Qtr 4','2014 Qtr 1','2014 Qtr 2','2014 Qtr 3','2014 Qtr 4','2015 Qtr 1','2015 Qtr 2','2015 Qtr 3','2015 Qtr 4','2016 Qtr 1','2016 Qtr 2','2016 Qtr 3','2016 Qtr 4','2017 Qtr 1','2017 Qtr 2','2017 Qtr 3','2017 Qtr 4','2018 Qtr 1','2018 Qtr 2','2018 Qtr 3','2018 Qtr 4','2019 Qtr 1','2019 Qtr 2','2019 Qtr 3','2019 Qtr 4'], 
colModel: [
{ name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 50, align: 'center',sortable: false, formatter: 'actions', frozen: true, hidedlg:true,
                  formatoptions: {
                    //url: $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam',"loadCostRowData"),
                    onSuccess:true,
                    afterSave: function(){
                       $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
                    //$(this).jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid',[{current:true}]);
                    jqGridFilter(null,$(this),0); 
                    jqGridFilter(filters , $(this),1); 
                    },

                    editbutton: true, 
                    delbutton: false,

                  },
              },
   {name: 'project_id',width:60,sortable:false,formatter:fontColorFormat,align: 'right',
    //sorttype:'int',
    frozen: true, hidedlg: true},
```

Here's the function to filter the grid rows:

```
    function jqGridFilter(filtersparam, grid, reload) {
 grid.setGridParam({
    postData: {
        filters: filtersparam
    },
    search: true
 });
 if(reload == 1){
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
 }
    };
```

And the filters are:

```
    var filters = { "groupOp": "OR", "rules": [{ "field": "y2012qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2012qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2013qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2014qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2015qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2016qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval1", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval2", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval3", "op": "ne", "data": "0" },{ "field": "y2017qval4", "op": "ne", "data": "0" }] };
```

The jqGridFilter function and the filters variable are declared and assigned before the grid is instantiated.

Any hints or suggestions where to look?

Thank you much!